# How to create game with DirectX 11 in C#

Tags: c#, c++, class, device

I installed DirectX 11 and DirectX SDK August 2009 on my PC.
I use `Device`,`PresentParameters` and other classes in C# to create a empty scene. Does C# uses DirectX 11 automatically? Is it possible to create a game with C# or do I need to use C++?
Excuse me, my English is not good.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but worth mentioning: have you looked into [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx)? I've used it before, and quite like it, and it makes it trivial to get your game onto Windows Phone or the Xbox Arcade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use DirectX11 in C# is via [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). See their documentation to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is realy best way